# How to pass state within state in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to pass my data array and favorites array which both I am setting in states. I want to pass my favorites array state in my data state. How can I achieve that?? My code looks like this

```
 class Favorites extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      favorites: [],
      data: [],

    };
  }

 axios
      .post(
        'http://staging.islamicmedia.com.au/wp-json/islamic-media/v1/user/media/library',
        data,
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);

        this.setState({
          data: res.data,

          favorites: res.data.data.favorite.filter((val) => val != null),
        });
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do that axios call in the componentDidMount:

```
class Favorites extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      favorites: [],
      data: [],

    };
  }
componentDidMount() {

 axios
      .post(
        'http://staging.islamicmedia.com.au/wp-json/islamic-media/v1/user/media/library',
        data,
      )
      .then((res) => {
        const favs = res.data.data.favorite.filter((val) => val !== null);

        this.setState({
          data: res.data,
          favorites: favs
        });
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: I am calling already in componentDidMount...I didn't write that above

Comment: I want in my axios.post after api call u  can see there is data is written i want to pass my favorites in my data there

Comment: Can you show the output of the console.log(res.data)? Your code looks ok

Comment: data:
bookmark: [{…}]
favorite: [{…}]
__proto__: Object
status: 200

it is something like this, i only want favoritess should come in my data not bookmarks

Comment: any suggestion plz??

Comment: Edited my answer, try it like that, it could be because you are doing a filter in the setState straight away